# Mybatis BindingException Parameter '__frch_e_0' not found

Tags: oracle, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to insert a list to Mybatis and getting the foloowing error:

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter '__frch_e_0' not found. Available parameters are [list]
```

Can you please let know what I'm missing. Thanks

DAO interface:

```
void saveErrorMessageList(List<ErrorMessage> emList);
```

XML:

```
<insert id="saveErrorMessageList" parameterType="java.util.List">
        {call
        declare
            ID PLS_INTEGER;
        begin
        <foreach collection="list" item="e" index="index" >
            SELECT SEQ_ERR_ID.NEXTVAL into ID FROM DUAL;

            INSERT INTO ERR (ERR_ID, CREAT_TS, 
            MSG_CD, MSG_TXT) values (ID,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
            #{e.code}, #{e.message});
        </foreach>
        end
        }
    </insert>
```

Error Message:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter '__frch_e_0' not found. Available parameters are [list]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:75)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:240)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.saveBeneErrorMessageList(Unknown Source)
    at ...
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Did You manage to fix it?

Comment: Sorry @Arsen....nope. I had to do indivdual inserts....didn't affect the performance much as the data size was small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check column name and bean field name in sql
- try to update mybatis version. when i use 3.3.0 have this error, but use 3.4.1 it is ok

Comment: Sorry for the late response...but upgrading the version to 3.4.2 fixed the issue. So I'm going to mark this as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check foreach tag for collection attribute. I feel value should be "emList" or add @Param (org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param) in interface method.

```
    <foreach collection="emList" item="e" index="index" >

        INSERT INTO ERR (ERR_ID, CREAT_TS, 
        MSG_CD, MSG_TXT) values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
        #{e.code}, #{e.message});
    </foreach>

</insert>
```

Comment: void saveList(@Param("emList") List<ErrorMessage> emList);

Comment: <insert id="saveList" parameterType="list">
     <foreach collection="emList" item="e" index="index" >...

Comment: Not sure but you can try this. remove parameterType from insert tag and keep everything same as above.

Comment: Why does it work in other methods without `@Param`?